# Polynomial asymptotes of $ f(x) = \frac{e^x}{e^{e|x|}} x^3(cos(\frac{1}{x}) - 1)(x^2 + sin(ln(|x| + 2))) + x^4 + \frac{xln(|xsinx|+ 1)}{x^2 - 1} $

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, asymptotics

For any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ and for a function $f$ defined on a ray $(a, \infty)$, the generalized asymptot of the function $f$ at $\infty$ is a polynomial $p$ such that:

$$ \displaystyle \lim_{x \to \infty} (x) - p(x) = 0$$

Similarly we can define the generalized asymptote of the function $f$ at $-\infty$.

For a function $f$ defined by the formula:

$$ f(x) = \frac{e^x}{e^{e|x|}} x^3(cos(\frac{1}{x}) - 1)(x^2 + sin(ln(|x| + 2))) + x^4 + \frac{xln(|xsinx|+ 1)}{x^2 - 1} $$

determine whether, at the points of indeterminacy of the function $f$ there are (classical) vertical asymptotes and find the generalized asymptotes of the function f at $\infty$ and at $-\infty$ (or justify that they do not exist).

I can't understand how to proceed with finding that generalized asymptotes $p(x)$ (they are polynominals).